# Generate one hour time interval array using pandas in python (import from csv) to predict next value

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, regression

I am trying to generate one hour one hour time interval to predict next value according to my data set imported from csv file. Here according to the time it will give outputs include in x column. This output is actual value and  I want to predict next value at 12.40 p.m (time) according to the past actual values and the time. For that I need to write an array for one hour to one hour continuously to predict the value with next time . I don't know how to proceed the time array after converting it.

subset of actual dataset;

```
Time    x
0:06:00 10
0:07:00 20
0:08:30 30
0:09:30 40
0:10:40 50
0:11:40 60
```

Can you give me any suggestion to me solve this code?

```
data = pd.read_csv('data4.csv')
data['Time'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Time']).astype(np.int64)//10**9)%86400
print(data['Time'])
```

Here I convert the time and I didn't know how to proceed the next step.

```
Time    g   p   c   x
0:06:00 63  0   0   10
0:07:00 63  0   2   20
0:08:00 104 11  0   30
0:09:00 93  0   50  40
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input and expected output? It is a little unclear what all you are asking. See [mcve] for info on how to write a question that is easily answered by SO users

Comment: @Andrew I changed it .

Comment: thanks for updating. I am still not sure of your expected output. It is not clear to me how the X variable relates to increases in Time. Time increments are [1:00, 1:30, 1:00, 1:10, 1:00], but the x variable increases be 10 each time.

Are you hoping to do a regression to predict time differences, or is there some rule-based procedure for determining them?

Comment: @Andrew Here I want to predict next value with time. Here I have actual data shown in time and x columns. So I want to predict value after one hour one hour. So my past value was with time 11.40 -60 . So I want to predict next value  at 12.40 ? So I thought to give first time interval array to my time series and then to predict the value. Because I can't plot my actual and predict value with time . That's why I thought to write first time array to my time series. Could you have any suggestions to solve this matter?

Comment: it sounds to me like you want to do forecasting. fbprophet is a pretty good library for that. You should also read up on ARIMA models or ARIMAX if you have other predictor variables besides time. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html will tell you how to handle time-series in pandas, but for the predictions you will need to look up the other terms I've mentioned.

Comment: @Andrew Can I use regression neural network model to predict next value with time and other variables? Like If I have three inputs and it affected to my actual outputs . By using them can I predict my next value using this model? I read ARIMA model ,but I don't know how to start my model to predict value. Here I attached subset of dataset again for your reference.

Comment: ARIMAX is used to include exogenous variables besides time. Maybe some type of nueral network would work, but always start with something simpler. Also, make sure you have a good understanding of prediction errors and other relevant model evaluation statistics. This is a very large are of study and there is a lot to know beyond learning how to run it in python. Many decisions you will have to make that cant all be explained in an API.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for helping me. I will try in simple method first.